# Server to server API authentication

Tags: authentication, api

We have an ASP.NET WEB API 2.0 that will be accessed by an MVC Core site. We want to restrict access to the API only to the MVC Core site (both sites will run on our VMs in Azure). Is it sufficient from an authentication and security perspective to pass a simple username and password in plaintext inside each HTTP request from the MVC Core site to the API as long as we are requiring HTTPS for all calls?

Comment: Certificate authentication is probably better

Comment: I second to that. Have your own CA, emit certificates for each server, have them only trust connections incoming with the trusted certificate.

Comment: Is it sufficient? Depends on your threat model.

Comment: Let's break it down: HTTPS= HTTP over TLS this is transport layer authentication and encryption.

Then it comes using of the API by this server which already represented it's TLS certificate to connect. API authentication is application layer.